# Morris.js file data

Tags: javascript, php, morris.js

I am using mysql for data and then i get them with php...

```
$array = data()->query("SELECT DATE(rezervacijaOpravljena) d, COUNT(id) visits FROM rezervacija GROUP BY d")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Than in javascript (morris.js data) i am using following script:

```
Morris.Line({         
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data:  $.ajax({             
            url: "dodajRezervacijo.php",
            success: function(html) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(html)[0]);   

            return JSON.parse(html)[0];         
            }
            })
        ,       
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'd',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['visits'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['Visits'],
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: true,
    resize: true
});
```

But it is not working. I am a  beginner in using ajax. Also is such use of php quering data good? or is better to have all things like(prepare and execute function separetly?)?

Comment: Get the data from your ajax call and in the success function call the morris graph.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer for you to accept since it provided a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data from your ajax call and in the success function call the morris graph.

That should do the trick.